# Attributing metadata to text

Tags: html, templating

I am working on a system that generates content based on a user's input.

**User Input:**
First Name: Chris
Current State: helpless

**Generated Content:**
This site is about *Chris* and he is currently *helpless*.

In order to let the user change the First Name or Current State later on, I need to associate the actual text in the page with the input names like so:

```
This site is about <span class="first-name">Chris</span> and he is currently 
<span class="current-state">helpless</span>.
```

How can I do this a **without using spans** like in the example above? I can't seem to find an HTML tag suitable for this.

**Edit:** It is hard to explain why I can't use spans. I am unable to use spans for this because I am using spans as targets that denote editable areas in the page. Using spans for the above purpose as well ends up causing issues that are far too complicated to describe here.

**Edit 2:** (including code from comments)

The issue is that I am wrapping all text nodes that are inside of `<p>` tags with the spans that denote editable content. Now, if I put spans inside of any of those `<p>` tags (namely spans that denote user inputs) I end up with real bad results.

It ends up looking like this:

```
<p>
    <span class="editable">This site is about</span> 
    <span class="first-name">Chris</span> 
    <span class="editable">and he is currently</span> 
    <span class="current-state">helpless</span>
    <span class="editable">.</span>
</p>
```

Instead of this:

```
<p>
    <span class="editable">This site is about Chris and he is currently helpless.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: What is wrong with using span? If you tell us that we could provide an alternative.

Comment: Use a <p> which is styled as inline, no margin/padding etc? Such as <p class="inline first-name">...</p>

Comment: I have considered it, but it seems an abuse of HTML semantics.

Comment: Why not target your spans {the ones you're using for editable content) using a class attribute?  That way you can free up the spans for this as well

Comment: It's not targeting that is the issue with those spans. The issue is that I am wrapping all text nodes that are inside of `<p>` tags with the spans that denote editable content.

Now, if I put spans inside of any of those `<p>` tags (namely spans that denote user inputs) I end up with real bad results.

Comment: It ends up looking like this: `<p><span class="editable">This site is about</span> <span class="first-name">Chris</span> <span class="editable">and he is currently</span> <span class="current-state">helpless</span><span class="editable">.</span></p>` Instead of this: `<p><span class="editable">This site is about Chris and he is currently helpless.</span></p>`